# how to paginated ScrollView with other animation

Tags: javascript, famo.us

how to change default animation in famo.us ScrollView
i have simple scrollview with 10 surfaces:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
var Engine           = require("famous/core/Engine");
var Surface          = require("famous/core/Surface");
var Scrollview       = require("famous/views/Scrollview");

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

var scrollview = new Scrollview({
    direction: 0,
    paginated: true
});
var surfaces = [];

scrollview.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    surface = new Surface({
        content: "Surface: " + (i + 1),
        size: [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight],
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 10) + ", 100%, 50%)",
            lineHeight: window.innerHeight/10 + "px",
            textAlign: "center"
        }
    });

    surface.pipe(scrollview);

    surfaces.push(surface);
}

mainContext.add(scrollview);
});
```

right now its just slide from right to left
how to make something like this animations, is there a way? http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/plugins/progress.php

Comment: Yes definitely you can augment the scrollview to do that. Which of the animations from the examples you pointed to do you want to do? If no one else has answered before tonight I'll get a code sample for you.

Comment: @aintnorest i am looking for Inverse Cover

Comment: The famo.us private repo has something very similar to your examples. I asked if I could post it but they're planning on releasing / showing it off tomorrow at the their event so just one more day.

Comment: @aintnorest tnx I will wait, you know why do they have private repo?

Comment: @aintnorest they releasing it in 5 of september

Comment: any updates on how to do this?